# run time error, variable b uninitialized

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code to get words from a line. Since I couldn't get any direct function for that, this is the code I wrote. I need to call it again and again in my main program hence I have made it a function. However, whenever I call it inside the main loop, it says variable b uninitialized. Any help is highly appreciated. TIA!

```
vector <string> output_words(string stri) //FUNCTION TO GET INDIVIDUAL WORDS FROM A LINE 
{
    vector <string> substring; // Contains words from single lines
    vector <string> output1;


    int b;

    //create variables that will act as "cursors". output words between them.
    size_t pos1 = 0;
    size_t pos2;

    string str;// = "Hello My Nme is Ruth";




    int a = str.length(); // abc[i] is a string in the vector, NOT THE VECTOR!

    for (int x = 0; x < a; x++)
    {
        pos2 = str.find(" ", pos1);
        //substring.resize(i);
        substring.resize(a); // Need to resize a vector so never points to zero
        substring[x] = str.substr(pos1, (pos2 - pos1));
        substring.push_back(substring[x]);
        //std::cout << "pos1:" << pos1 << ", pos2:" << pos2 << std::endl;
        pos1 = pos2 + 1; // sets pos1 to the next character after pos2. 
                         //so, it can start searching the next " ".
        if (x > 0)
        {
            if (substring[0] == substring[x])
            {
                substring.erase(substring.begin() + x);
                //one_string.erase(one_string.end());
                b = x;
                goto label;
            }
        }
    }


label: for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        output1.resize(b);
        output1[i] = substring[i];

    }

    return output1;
}
```

Comment: Think about what happens if the string is empty. Also I would use a break instead of the goto.

Comment: Besides your question, but why are you using `goto` here? It's use seems entirely unjustified.

Comment: What is `goto` doing in here? That's the nuclear weapon option of flow control.

Comment: _"it says variable b uninitialized"_ Your question implies you think it's wrong to say that. Why?

Comment: Okay got it. Dunno what I was thinking. Also changed that goto to break. Works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting the variable `int b;` into anything, it is literally uninitialized. All you have to do is set `b` to something(usually 0).

Answer (score 0):

You have not updated value of b. you have just declared variable b in line 6 and not initialized.so please initialize it to appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to assign to `b` inside `for { if { if { /* * */ } } }` then it is possibly not assigned any value (if certain conditions are not satisfied). If this happens then `label: for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)` is trying to access un-initialized `b` that would lead to `undefined behavior`.